# SQLAlchemy query

Tags: database, sqlalchemy

I'm working on a web app and an db which deals with the following
entities: computers, computer containers (computer_sets) and rules. It
a firewall management tool. I'm having some troubles dealing with
computer objects, because those computers stored within a computer_set
are not the same objects as those computers not contained within a
computer_set: a stand-alone computer can be in a rule, but a
computer_set computer cannot be in a rule, i.e, only the container is
allowed to be in a rule (I know I know, this is a mess, but I didn't
create the firewall, I'm just programming a management tool :).

I created a DB (with SQLite) and I'm using SQLAlchemy. Thus, I created
the classes Computer, ComputerSet, ComputerSetComputer and Rule and
the corresponding tables
.
Now, in my application, I need to list all those computer objects.
However, when I query the computers table, I get Computer objects and
when I query my computerset_computers table, I get ComputerSetComputer
objects. I would like to get a query object containing all my
computers no matter whether or not they belong to a computer set. This
way, I would be able to slice the query object and do pagination. Any ideas? I could change my DB design, though I cannot change the underlying concepts of a Computer,
a Rule, .etc.

Thanks for your time,
gsandorx :)

Comment: Are you asking how to do a Union between two tables that contain "Computer"?  Please provide relevant code for the things you're trying to union.

Comment: looks like someone answered your Q on the mailing list.

Comment: for reference: http://groups.google.com/group/sqlalchemy/browse_frm/thread/56af53ea50cd2578?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways to solve this problem: use union in low-level queries or use inheritance in model definition. I think the later is more convenient, since you get model objects from queries. Assuming you have `ComputerBase` abstract class and two its subclassess `Computer` and `ComputerSetComputer`, `session.query(ComputerBase).all()` will return the mixed list of all `Computer` and `ComputerSetComputer` objects.